# MVC Core Controller Declaration

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In the code line below below, what does the second Controller mean?

Is that a data variable declaration for `HelloWorldController`?

```
HelloWorldController : **Controller**
```

From [MSDN Adding Controller](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-controller)

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Text.Encodings.Web;

namespace MvcMovie.Controllers
{
    public class HelloWorldController : Controller
    {
        // 
        // GET: /HelloWorld/

        public string Index()
        {
            return "This is my default action...";
        }

        // 
        // GET: /HelloWorld/Welcome/ 

        public string Welcome()
        {
            return "This is the Welcome action method...";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means `Controller` is the [base type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.basetype(v=vs.110).aspx) of `HelloWorldController`, enabling you to access all of its protected methods, and allowing it to be stored anywhere a `Controller` can be stored.

This relates to the [inheritance](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/oop-concepts/inheritance.html) part of object-oriented programming, which is a topic much too broad for a complete explanation here.